# Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed mushr mujoco simulation

Tags: python, ros, mujoco

Error

[image: 1]

I've been trying to start the MuSHR simulation that uses mujoco to work. I'm having issues with it working as whenever I try to create a catkin workspace, they give the "invoking 'make -j1 -l1' failed" error. What is really confusing is that it references mushr_mujoco_ros_node file however such a file doesn't exist in the mushr_mujoco_ros directory.Any help is appreciated

No node directory

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don’t have GLUT installed. It includes certain libraries that are needed when linking. You can install it via

`sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev`